# Atom editor not working after reboot / OSX

Tags: macos, atom-editor

I'm not sure if it's the correct stack platform but since some time my Atom Editor don't start after I restart or boot my Mac.

I need to reinstall the app. I also uninstall the hole application with AppCleaner and install it new without success. After the reboot I've got this error message:

```
Process:               Atom [916]
Path:                  /Applications/Atom.app/Contents/MacOS/Atom
Identifier:            com.github.atom
Version:               ???
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Atom [916]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2019-09-26 22:42:03.502 +0200
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.14.6 (18G95)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        67A52C69-B8B4-FB36-FAF9-2F2D5A429F99


Time Awake Since Boot: 65 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (Code Signature Invalid)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    Namespace CODESIGNING, Code 0x1

kernel messages:

VM Regions Near 0 (cr2):
--> 
    __TEXT                 000000010f3a4000-000000010f3a5000 [    4K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  

Thread 0 Crashed:
0                                   0x0000000119caa000 _dyld_start + 0

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000000000000000  rcx: 0x0000000000000000  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000000000  rsi: 0x0000000000000000  rbp: 0x0000000000000000  rsp: 0x00007ffee085bc30
   r8: 0x0000000000000000   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10: 0x0000000000000000  r11: 0x0000000000000000
  r12: 0x0000000000000000  r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x0000000000000000  r15: 0x0000000000000000
  rip: 0x0000000119caa000  rfl: 0x0000000000000200  cr2: 0x0000000000000000

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x00000000
Trap Number:     0


Binary Images:
       0x10f3a4000 -        0x10f3a4ff3 + (0) <4FAD2A7B-B418-358C-949F-1104B0620579> 
       0x119ca9000 -        0x119d1370f + (655.1.1) <DFC3C4AF-6F97-3B34-B18D-7DCB23F2A83A> 

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 1564
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=608K resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=608K(100%)
Writable regions: Total=8400K written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=8400K(100%)

                                VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     =======  ======= 
STACK GUARD                       56.0M        1 
Stack                             8192K        1 
__DATA                             232K        3 
__LINKEDIT                         176K        2 
__TEXT                             432K        2 
shared memory                        8K        2 
===========                     =======  ======= 
TOTAL                             64.8M       11 

Model: MacBookPro10,1, BootROM 257.0.0.0.0, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2,3 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.3f36
Graphics: kHW_IntelHD4000Item, Intel HD Graphics 4000, spdisplays_builtin
Graphics: kHW_NVidiaGeForceGT650MItem, NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, spdisplays_pcie_device, 1 GB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333531533642465238432D50422020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333531533642465238432D50422020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xEF), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.190.33 AirPortDriverBrcm4360-1325.2)
Bluetooth: Version 6.0.14d3, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM256E, 251 GB
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: USB3.0 Hub
USB Device: USB2.0 Hub
USB Device: Keyboard Hub
USB Device: Apple Keyboard
USB Device: Game Mouse
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 23.4
```

OSX is on 10.14.6
Atom 1.40.1

**Updated:**

with `atom --safe` I’ve got this message in the terminal:

`LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed for the application /Applications/Atom.app with error -10810.`

with `atom -f` this error:

`/usr/local/bin/atom: line 192: 2506 Killed: 9 "$ATOM_PATH/$ATOM_APP_NAME/Contents/MacOS/$ATOM_EXECUTABLE_NAME" --executed-from="$(pwd)" --pid=$$ "$@"`

**Update2**

it works till version 1.38.2. since 1.39 the app chrashed

Comment: `Code Signature Invalid` would suggest it needs re-installing.

Comment: I have been reinstalling the software many times. And after every reboot or shutdown this error occurs again.

Comment: If you open it from the UI (not the command line) do you get the niggle dialog about it being untrusted?  If so you can then force-load it via Security & Privacy (or whatever it's called) from within System Preferences.  That might solve it.

Comment: The dialog with the error also appear when I open the app over the UI. And the app is also on "Full Disk Access" under Security

Comment: it works till version 1.38.2. since 1.39 the app chrashed

Answer (score 0):

You could try resigning with Jonathan Levin's [jtool](http://www.newosxbook.com/tools/jtool.tgz)

```
jtool --sign  /Applications/Atom.app/Contents/MacOS/Atom
```

backup original `Atom` executable

And replace `/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/MacOS/Atom` with resulting `out.bin` (i.e. rename  `out.bin` to `/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/MacOS/Atom`)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar problem in my Mac wherein Atom kept crashing after I had 'Force Quit' it some time back in the day. I deleted the `~/.atom` folder as mentioned [here](https://discuss.atom.io/t/atom-fails-to-open-mac/15095/10) and then it worked like a breeze.